# Java: Sort child based on data in Firebase Database

Tags: java, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Image here. Data does not sort accordingly like I wanted (O+, O+, A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGGAi.png)

Currently, I have data that stored exactly like in the picture above, I want to make all the blood groups to be placed accordingly. For example, It will have only 0+ until the lists end. It will continue with different blood groups such A+, A- etc.

Can firebase actually sort that data? I was looking around, but could not find anything

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Firebase Console, all the nodes are sorted lexicographically by key and this can't be changed.

**However**, when you retrieve the data on the client, you can choose to sort by one of the child properties. This way they will be sorted by the time they are shown to the client. For example:

```
// the reference to where your people are stored
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
// create the query
Query peopleBloodTypeQuery = mDatabase.child("people").orderByChild("bloodgroup");
// query the people
peopleBloodTypeQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // add a child added listener
    @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        // do whatever here - I just print the key of each added child
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but im currently using java for this project that I'm working on

Comment: Apologies, you didn't mention that in your post.